# Combining all CSS in one file or dynamic loading then?

Tags: css, performance, pagespeed

I want to know if is better to have all CSS files minified and combined in a single file, that will have all the styles of the site, or having smallest files that will be loaded on demand depending of page visited.

Answer (score 1):

I would say minifi right away and allow browsers to cache the information. it might take slightly longer to load the first visit, but all later visits will be faster.
Here Is a blog post I found explaining it.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceAndEaseOfMinifyingYourCSSAndJavaScriptAndOptimizingPNGsForYourBlogOrWebsite.aspx